# Smoothness of Squared distance function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Fix a non-empty compact subset $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $d_K(x):=\min_{z \in K} \,\|z-x\|$ be the map sending any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to its distance from $K$.

Suppose that:

- $K$ is *regular*; i.e. it has a non-empty interior $\overset{\circ}{K}$ and the closure of $\overset{\circ}{K}$ is $K$.
- $K$ $C^{k+1}$ boundary,
- $K$ is convex (actually a convex body by the above).

Then:

- **Question 1:** Is there some $0<p<\infty$ such that: $d_K^p$ also $k$-times continuously differentiable?
- **(Backup) Question 2:** Are there reasonable "geometric" conditions on $K$ which will guarantee that $d_K^p$ is $C^k$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$; for some $0<p<\infty$?

Note: I recall seeing something if $K$ is a convex body (i.e.: convex with codimension $0$ but I can't remember if I'm thinking of them correctly).

Comment: The stated requirements won't work (consider a sphere with a "dimple"), but replacing simply connected with convex should suffice.

Comment: @Kajelad Very interesting point.  I incorporated this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k=0$ case follows from the triangle inequality. The $k>0$ case is more interesting:

Let $\partial K$ denote the boundary of $K$, and let $N:\partial K\to\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the outward pointing unit normal vector field, which is $C^k$. Define a map $F:\partial K\times (0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ by $F(x,t)=x+tN(x)$. One can show that $F$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism, and that $d_k(F(x,t))=t$. It follows from this that $d_K^p$ is $C^k$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$ for all $p$.

To show that $F$ is a diffeomorphism requires a few steps. One can apply the following facts:

- Given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K$, the distance from $x$ to $K$ is minimized by the unique point $y\in\partial K$ for which $x-y=cN(y)$ for some $c>0$ (this implies $F$ is injective and surjective).
- The shape operator $S$ of $\partial K$ is $C^{k-1}$ and positive semidefinte due to convexity.
- Identifying $T_{(x,t)}(\partial K\times(0,\infty))$ with $T_x\partial K\times \mathbb{R}$, we have $d_{(x,t)}F(u,r)=u+tS(x)u+rN(x)$, which is invertible and $C^{k-1}$, thus $F$ is a $C^k$ diffeomorphism.

Comment: I'm not sure "should be possible constitutes an answer (with out at-least a reference)"

Comment: @James_T Agreed in hindsight; I've added a bit more detail about how it can be proven.

Comment: Right, and its obviously $C^{\infty}$ on $K$ (since it is constant $0$ there..so both these gives the conclusion).  Also, I'm not very familiar with this shape operator business; do you know of a relevant reference?

Comment: @James_T I don't know of a reference for this specific fact, but the shape operator is discussed is discussed in most introductory texts on Riemannian geometry which cover (hyper)surfaces, e.g. Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* or [Shifrin's *Differential Geometry*](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) (which cover 2-dimensional surfaces) or Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds* (which is somewhat more advanced, but covers the general case).

Comment: @James_T Also note that this only shows that $d_K^p$ is $C^k$ on the compliment of $K$; it won't be as smooth on $\partial K$ since locally it will look like the function$$f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\begin{cases}0&x_1\le 0\\x_1^p&x_1>0\end{cases}$$which is never $C^\infty$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused since (see [Lemma 14.16] of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61798-0) shows that it must be $C^k$ on some fattening of $K$

Comment: That lemma seems to be addressing a slightly different case: there they define $d$ as the distance to the boundary of $\Omega$, and only fatten the boundary in one direction, since $\Gamma_\mu\subseteq\overline\Omega$. Also, there's the subtlety of dealing with smoothness on nonopen sets. In this case we likewise have that $d_K^p$ is smooth on the closure $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K}$ for $p\in\mathbb{N}$, but since $d_K^p$ is identically zero on $K^\circ$, we cannot extend further.

Comment: @James_T as a possibly illustrative example, $f(x)=|x|$ is smooth on $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$, but we cannot extend either of these intervals.